# Creating a generic LINQ function to return the type that is passed in

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Two LINQ methods that do the same thing but take and return different types

```
private IQueryable<Type1>FilterBySomething(IQueryable<Type1> results)
{
    if (ThisField!= null)
    {
        results = results.Where(x => x.Thisfield == ThisField.Value);
    }
    return results;
}

private IQueryable<Type2>FilterBySomething(IQueryable<Type2> results)
{
    if (ThisField!= null)
    {
        results = results.Where(x => x.Thisfield == ThisField.Value);
    }
    return results;
}
```

The problem with this is duplication. I'd like one generic function that does this, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: What have you tried? What can't you figure out? (And aren't you missing a space after `IQueryable<Type#>`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Introduce new interface:

   ```
   interface IThisfieldSupported
   {
       string Thisfield {get;set;}
   }
   ```
2. Set restrictions:

   ```
   private IQueryable<Type1> FilterBySomething<Type1>(IQueryable<Type1> results) where Type1 : class, IThisfieldSupported
   {
       if (ThisField!= null)
       {
           results = results.Where(x => x.Thisfield == ThisField.Value);
       }
       return results;
   }
   ```
3. Call it with different classes, but implement `IThisfieldSupported` in this classes:

   ```
   class Data : IThisfieldSupported
   {
       string Thisfield { get;set; }
       int Id { get;set; }
   }
   ...
   var data = new Data[10];
   var result = FilterBySomething(data);
   ```

Comment: Nice Answer. You can't use T in this cause because the compiler has no enforcement of whether ThisField is implemented. Interfaces are the way to go.