Entity Framework same schema, different table, one sort function
Is it possible to have 2 different Entity Framework model for 2 different SQL Server Views, which have same schema, and have them go through a single sort function?
eg.
public class TableOne
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
}

public class TableTwo
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
}

public class DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TableOne> TableOne { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TableTwo> TableTwo { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<TableOne/TableTwo> SortFunction(IEnumerable<TableOne/TableTwo> list)


Add interface:
public interface ITable
{
    string One { get; }
    string Two { get; }
}

public class TableOne : ITable {
    public string One {get; set;}
    public string Two {get; set;}
}

public class TableTwo : ITable {
    public string One {get; set;}
    public string Two {get; set;}
}

IEnumerable<ITable> SortFunction(IEnumerable<ITable> list)

And maybe, you should use IQueryable<ITable>:
IEnumerable<ITable> SortFunction(IQueryable<ITable> list)


IQueryable and this function should be Generic function.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Doesn't that depends on whether or not you're using [DbFunction] or not? - the OP didn't clarify.

Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632934/creating-a-generic-linq-function-to-return-the-type-that-is-passed-in/32633082#32633082
